# C# tool that formats an HTML string before sending it to the client

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, webforms

Is there a c# tool that will take a large string of HTML created with StringBuilder and format it before passing it to the client?

It would also be pretty cool if there was a tool that removed all white space and minimized the HTML before sending it to the client.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

yes you can do this by using

[Web Markup Minifier: Core](http://nugetmusthaves.com/Package/WebMarkupMin.Core)

to see how to do it you can view this [link](https://github.com/Taritsyn/WebMarkupMin/wiki/HTML-Minifier)

there are other nuget packages over [here](http://nugetmusthaves.com/Tag/minify) as well for the same pupose

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using WebMarkupMin.Core;

namespace WebMarkupMin.Sample.ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
    const string htmlInput = @"<!DOCTYPE html>
                                <html>
                                    <head>
                                        <meta charset=""utf-8"" />
                                        <title>The test document</title>
                                        <link href=""favicon.ico"" rel=""shortcut icon"" type=""image/x-icon"" />
                                        <meta name=""viewport"" content=""width=device-width"" />
                                        <link rel=""stylesheet"" type=""text/css"" href=""/Content/Site.css"" />
                                    </head>
                                    <body>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>

                                        <script src=""http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js""></script>
                                        <script>
                                            (window.jquery) || document.write('<script src=""/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js""><\/script>');
                                        </script>
                                    </body>
                                </html>";

            var htmlMinifier = new HtmlMinifier();

            MarkupMinificationResult result = htmlMinifier.Minify(htmlInput,
                generateStatistics: true);
            if (result.Errors.Count == 0)
            {
                MinificationStatistics statistics = result.Statistics;
                if (statistics != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Original size: {0:N0} Bytes",
                        statistics.OriginalSize);
                    Console.WriteLine("Minified size: {0:N0} Bytes",
                        statistics.MinifiedSize);
                    Console.WriteLine("Saved: {0:N2}%",
                        statistics.SavedInPercent);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Minified content:{0}{0}{1}",
                    Environment.NewLine, result.MinifiedContent);
            }
            else
            {
                IList<MinificationErrorInfo> errors = result.Errors;

                Console.WriteLine("Found {0:N0} error(s):", errors.Count);
                Console.WriteLine();

                foreach (var error in errors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Line {0}, Column {1}: {2}",
                        error.LineNumber, error.ColumnNumber, error.Message);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not answer [off topic questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). It just encourages more people to ask off topic questions.

Comment: Do you know which NuGet package is the one for this library? I tried TidyNetPortable and it doesn't seem to be it.

Comment: at the time when i used it i use it as an dll not as nuget package so you can use Web Markup Minifier: Core and i am also editing the answer as per this